# How to make sure user authenticates in Blazor when navigating to a page, but redirecting to that page after sign in?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-b2c

I have successfully set up Azure ADB2C authentication with my Server-Blazor app.  Users can successfully login, but after that login, they are currently always redirected to the same (pre-configured) page/url.

What I actually want now, is the following logic:

- A user navigates to a page (`/registrationwizard/02`, for example).
- When the user is already signed in, the logic in that page just shows whatever is needed (I can do that with `AuthorizeView`)
- But when the user is not yet signed in, the user should be redirected to the login logic, I currently do that with a `<a href='MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn'>sign in</a>` link.
- And after that sign in logic, the user should be returned back to the requested original page (`/registrationwizard/02`), and not the preconfigured page in the startup logic. (`signin-oidc`)

I did some searches, but cannot seem to find this (while I believe this should be rather straight forward?)

This is the (I believe) relevant part of my startup logic:
(have been trying to fiddle with the `ReturnUrlParameter` parameter as well)

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
        options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
            options.Scope.Add("https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/api/data");
            options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            // Played around with this parameter too
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
        }
        ,
        options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        }
        );

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Thanks

Comment: change your link to <a href='MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn?returnurl=....'>, after sign in, navigate to that returnurl.

Comment: I had already tried that, but it seems to ignore that returnUrl value ...  The redirect goes to the home page

Comment: did you check and change identity default return url setting? check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cookie-settings

Comment: I added those settings with ConfigureApplicationCookie indeed, but same result...

Answer (score 1):

### Revised Intermediate Answer

You are correct on `ReturnUrlParameter`.  You also need to add the `AccessDeniedPath` option.

I've added them to AppSettings:

```
    "ReturnUrlParameter": "custompath",
    "AccessDeniedPath": "/"
```

You should then be able to manually do this:

```
https://localhost:5001/MicrosoftIdentity/account/signin?custompath=%2fcounter
```

However, it doesn't appear to work.  I have a project that I'm updating next month moving from custom to AzureADB2C authentication and it will have the same problem!

I've raised an issue with the Aspnetcore team on Github.  It's probably a documentation issue.

Issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45024

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for your support.  When doing that, I get a "NotFound", when redirected to Login.  And when I change the NavigateTo to LoginRedirect, I end up in an endless redirect loop (as the actual login does not seem to happen).  So, it seems the the /Login is not configured rightly?

Comment: I just keep thinking it's related to the fact that my AzB2C application has /signin-oidc configured as the redirect url.  That handles the authentication tokens, etc, I think.  But it seems it's not leveraging the returnUrl.

Comment: Thanks.  But that "Login" page is not existing in my solution, as I use the default AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp call.  I hope to avoid having to scaffold those identity parts...

Comment: See my revised answer.  I've removed some old no longer relevant comments.

Comment: thanks.  it's not that I need a specific returnUrl parameter, I would also be happy to use a default one, but that itself also does not seem to work.  thanks for your effort, watching the issue now